# How to programmatically add Boostrap Modal attr to button Or link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the different modals and need to assign them to corresponding links

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Store 1</a>
```

Example if a  with value (or text ) ***Store 1*** is **clicked** I would like to programmatically add theses attribute to  with the text ***Store 1***

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal
```

and Open Modal `#myModal` onclick

1. Check if link contain certain text the assign corresponding attr.

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: $("#myModal").modal()

Comment: <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Store 1</a>   <--- need to check if value is 'Store 1'

Comment: @werahaj what have you tried already?

Comment: @Alisson  $('a:contains("Store 1")').addAttr('some attr');

Answer (score 0):

Write onclick events for anchor tag like below and pass values as you lik.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return openStore('Store 1')" >Store 1</a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return openStore('Store 2')" >Store 2</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function openStore(storeType)
    {
        if(storeType === 'Store 1') {
            $("#store1Modal").modal();
        } else if (storeType === 'Store 2') {
            $("#store2Modal").modal();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU @swaroop assuming there is no onclick="return openStore('Store 1')?

Comment: we have click attribute for anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the anchor tag have text `Store 1` and then you need to add the attributes like below.

```
$("a.btn").click(function(){
   if($(this).text() == "Store 1") {
       $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
       $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
   }
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("a.btn").click(function(){
  if($(this).text() == "Store 1") {
      $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
      $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Store 1</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fb9zz5p1/9/)